# Pandas Series with dtype=int defaulting to int32 instead of int64 on 64-bit Python environment

Tags: python, pandas, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm working on a Windows system with a 64-bit version of Python (Python 3.10.13, packaged by Anaconda, Inc.). When I run Python, the header indicates that it's a 64-bit environment: "Python 3.10.13 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:24:38) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32". I am not sure why it shows win32, since I have a win64 machine

I've verified the bitness through various methods.
First using the following code, which correctly shows that I'm running a 64-bit Python environment.:

```
import platform
import sys

assert platform.architecture()[0] == "64bit"
assert sys.maxsize > 2**32
```

Next, I checked my conda version with `conda info`, which gives `platform : win-64`.

However, when I use Pandas (version 2.1.3) and create an empty Series with dtype=int:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.Series([1,2,3], dtype=int).dtype)
```

It shows 'int32' instead of 'int64'. I expected it to default to int64 in a 64-bit environment. If I do not specify int, like `print(pd.Series([1,2,3]).dtype)` it prints'int64'.

Why is Pandas defaulting to int32 instead of int64 in my 64-bit Python environment, and how can I ensure that it defaults to int64?

I do not want to explicitly convert all my DataFrames with .astype("int64"), since that could result in failing tests on other machines.

Comment: If an int32 is not big enough then you need to specify int64 to get platform-independent correctness. Otherwise, what does it matter if the default is int32 or int64?

Comment: The problem occurs in testing, since I am using `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`, which will fail if one column uses int64 and the other uses int32. In my code, I sometimes need to explicitly cast to an integer with `.astype(int)`, which is converted to int32. However the default that my values are casted to, if I do not specify int, is int64. It seems strange that two different integer types are casted through, which should be the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @txg If you just have to compare numeric values without their dtypes, maybe what you want is `assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_dtype=False)`.

Comment: In this situation it would work, although I need to be wary with using it in situations where floats may arise for example. Some situations (floats) might impact the code. And it still raises the question why in some cases it is casted to int32 and some cases int64.