pandas forcing data types mutates data
I have a stock valuation program. The main data type is the built-in Python dictionary.
Pandas df is only used for calculations because it is easier than manipulating dictionaries.
I am experiencing weird data set mutation by forcing desired data types with astype()
Code for this particular column df = df.astype(DF_DTYPES) - this particular column is defined by dictionary DF_DTYPES where {'is_inco_oper': int}
Result
0     170914000
1      63275000
2     248049000
3     746273000
4    1067817000
5    1022510000
6    1218091000
7    3415195000
8    3669382000
9    2531232000
Name: is_inco_oper, dtype: int64
0     170914000
1      63275000
2     248049000
3     746273000
4    1067817000
5    1022510000
6    1218091000
7    -879772296
8    -625585296
9   -1763735296
Name: is_inco_oper, dtype: int32

Pandas dataframe is created by df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary). The original column is int64. After astype(), the same column is int32, and rows 7-9 are mutated.
Why? It makes no sense. What am I doing wrong, please? Is it a bug?
I force data types because sqlite3 export/import screws everything up, and I end up with integer values with .0 for example 153.0
Any suggestion how to keep consistent values without unwanted mutation of data, please?

Those values are above the limits of int32. (2 ** 31) - 1 = 2147483647 is the max positive value you can store in int32. You can use uint32 if your values are below 2 ** 32 - 1 = 4294967295.

Yes, but why pandas force it out of range if original value is int64. Looks like one should force always the fully defined type instead of general int

if it is already int64 why are you converting it?

@DavidHajes what is "DF_DTYPES"?

@Dogbert updated original question. It is basically a dictionary of all 49 columns with desired types like {'is_inco_oper': int}

@DavidHajes is the code being run on a 32-bit machine? I can't reproduce this on my 64-bit machine. astype with the int function as the type gives me int64.

@Dogbert no, who still uses 32b nowadays? :-D What is interesting, it seems to do random stuff. I have another dataset of different stock, and there seems to be no issues. I have those issues since I started to code this app. It does randomly, I thought it was caused by use of global variables/df. After complete redesign without global variables. It does same crap randomly.

I have reported a bug on pandas github. There was similar issue reported back in 2013, which suppose to be resolved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614909/pandas-series-with-dtype-int-defaulting-to-int32-instead-of-int64-on-64-bit-pyth. In any case, you should be passing exact types, e.g. 'int64'.

yep, that is a kludge, but should not happen. BUG

I also can't repro. What version of Python and Pandas are you using? Could you grab the same info as the question Dogbert posted? (like conda info → "platform")

For reference, the bug you posted (#58907)

I have also included the dictionary in above by bug report

{'is_inco_oper': np.int64}

it is basically old issue with numpy that uses default int32 for some unknown reason (Allegedly compatibility among pandas int, numpy & C long).
Solution is to force pandas extended dtypes to avoid unexpected behaviour.
